# Random Forest Classifier Error with Python - Index out of bounds

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

everyone! As a quick heads up, I'm following this link in order to try to do a random forest classifier:
https://towardsdatascience.com/random-forest-in-python-24d0893d51c0

This assignment is about hotel data and finding the best algorithm to predict.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score,mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split #I know all these modules aren't applicable, but I copied and pasted them from a similar project and will tidy that up later.

features = pd.read_csv('train.csv', iterator=True).get_chunk(100000)

features = features.dropna()

# Use numpy to convert to arrays
import numpy as np
# Labels are the values we want to predict
labels = np.array(features['hotel_cluster'])
# Remove the labels from the features
# axis 1 refers to the columns
features= features.drop('hotel_cluster', axis = 1)
# Saving feature names for later use
feature_list = list(features.columns)
# Convert to numpy array
features = np.array(features)

train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
```

So far, so good, until I get to this cell:

```
# The baseline predictions are the historical averages
baseline_preds = test_features[:, feature_list.index('hotel_cluster')]
# Baseline errors, and display average baseline error
baseline_errors = abs(baseline_preds - test_labels)
print('Average baseline error: ', round(np.mean(baseline_errors), 2))
```

Here is the error received:

```
ValueError: 'hotel_cluster' is not in list
```

I feel like I know why this happened. They had me drop the target variable, 'hotel_cluster' so it couldn't be included. However, I did this because the link told me to. So when I fix it and keep it in there, the error received is:

```
IndexError: index 23 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 23
```

I feel like something is either off with that link or wrong with my dataset. I want to stick with this link because it got me so much farther than the others. Here's a screenshot with the head and info. Please let me know if I'm missing anything. Thanks!
[Head/Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHsFY.png)

Comment: you should put the link of the data

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/c/expedia-hotel-recommendations/data?select=train.csv

Answer (score 0):

the method `index()` of a `list` object returns the index of the queried element in a list, i.e. an *integer* (`int`) value. As a side node: a `pandas.DataFrame` object would expect a column name, i.e. a *string* (`str`). Since you have a matrix (`numpy.ndarray`), you are required to slice it by integers -- so you're OK. (BTW, `pandas.DataFrame` have a build-in method for conversion to `numpy.ndarrays` that is `pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy()`).
If you do not drop the `'hotel_cluster'` column from the table `features`, the converted matrix must have the same width as the original table -- and this also means, the same width as the length of the previously stored list of colum names `feature_list`. Check:

```py
assert(len(feature_list) == feature.shape[1])
```

I guess that you were using a Python interactive console and some bug sneaked there into your code. If you do not drop any column, `test_features[:, feature_list.index('hotel_cluster')]` should work. (you way want to rerun the code without the dropping line)

Besides this, keep the line when dropping `'hotel_cluster'` and replace the indexing line with `baseline_preds = test_labels` as this seems to be the intention anyway. However, the rest of the code is of no use then and the description in the comments also won't suit a *baseline prediction*. I guess that you want to do some moving average thing here.

**colsing node**: Welcome to stackoverflow. The next time, please strip your code to an absolute [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Random Forest has no relation to you current prolbem (all `sklearn` imports) and downloading 3 GB of data is most likely not necessary to reproduce your error. It may be beneficial creating a toy example, e.g.

```py
features = pd.DataFrame([list(range(5)), list(range(5, 10))], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

Comment: Thanks, Max! I'm checking this out right now. So far, the assert command does not create any issues. I'll be poring through the rest of the comment now.

Comment: Thanks! So I did choose not to drop the hotel_cluster, but it also resulted in a baseline error of 0, which strikes me as unusual as when it comes to predictive analytics, having a perfect analysis is basically impossible. I feel like I should be dropping the cluster?

Comment: you are reading the column names of the data frame `features` *after* already dropping the column `'hotel_cluster'`. So indexing the very same data frame (also it is split to training & test data) by the key `'hotel_cluster` is already impossible (you have a matrix anyway) but you want to do this neatly by getting the index of the list of column names, in which the name has never been stored because you read the column names *after* dropping this column. This seems to be a double error. If this is not please add a bit more focus to your question.